# how can I get the text before and after the "-" (dash)

Tags: java, android, string, split

I have a String and I want to get the words before and after the " - " (dash). How can I do that?

example:
String:

```
"First part - Second part"
```

output:

```
first: First part
second: Second part
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

With no error-checking or safety, this could work:

```
String[] parts = theString.split("-");
String first = parts[0];
String second = parts[1];
```

Comment: That's Great , Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Easy: use the [`String.split`](http://java.xiruibin.com/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method.

**Example :**

```
final String s = "Before-After";
final String before = s.split("-")[0]; // "Before"
final String after = s.split("-")[1]; // "After"
```

Note that I'm leaving error-checking and white-space trimming up to you!

Answer (score 7):

```
int indexOfDash = s.indexOf('-');
String before = s.substring(0, indexOfDash);
String after = s.substring(indexOfDash + 1);
```

Reading [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) helps finding answers to such questions.

Answer (score 2):

```
    @Test
    public void testSplit() {
        String str = "First part - Second part";
        String strs[] = str.split("-");
        for (String s : strs) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
```

**Output**:

> First part
>
> Second part

Comment: I tried it myself and it works as expected. The only thing you have to do is to trim the strings.

Answer (score 1):

use [`indexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) and [`substring()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) method of `String` class, for the example given you can also use [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method